# Align zero on second y axis (.twinx)

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I make sure that the zeros of my two y-Axis are aligned?

```
fig2 = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig2.add_gridspec(2, 1)
a30 = fig2.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
a30.plot(f[0:150], c[0:150], color='blue')

a31 = a30.twinx()
a31.plot(abs(f)[0:150],p_h[0:150], color='red')
plt.show()
```

as of now there is an offset between them.
I have tried adding `a30.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))`
but no luck.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zslm2.png)

Could I do this with a matplotlib.ticker-function? There are
`matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator(numticks=None, presets=None), set_params(base=None, offset=None), tick_values(vmin, vmax), get_offset(), set_offset_string(ofs), matplotlib.ticker.IndexLocator(base, offset)`
,which all sound very promising but I did not succeed in implementing them with any effect in my code.

Comment: Can you just set the y limit on both of them to the same value? `plt.ylim(-1, 5)` or something like that?

Comment: thanks, I had limits for just one of the plots, the trick was setting them for both :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a30.set_ylim(0,c.max())
a31.set_ylim(0,p_h.max())
```

works, or any other maximum.